# Why does the first element in the list get highlighted?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to generate the navigation bar in my Chrome Extension, however for some reason, it keeps highlighting the first element and I'm not sure why.  There is no CSS other than the default Bootstrap CSS

**My code**

```
<ul class="nav">  
  <li><a id="btnHome" href="#" title="Home"><img src="img/bk.png"/></a></li> 
  <li class="current"><a href="popup.html" title="Notifications"><i class="icon-bell current"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="spaces.html" title="Spaces" ><i class="icon-th-list"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="options.html" target="_blank" title="Options" ><i class="icon-wrench "></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**My results**

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/b2LxH/

This doesn't seem to happen in normal browsing as per the jsfiddle.  It have only tested this on Chrome on OSX.  It's an extension so not sure if thats having any impact.

Comment: Do your images have a default border around them?

Comment: you check if the image look like highlighted?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it could be a border inside the image file.

Comment: Could you please share url or your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Even if I change the image to a font awesome icon, it still highlights it

Comment: this proccess will be very faster if you could provid a fiddle or share a link of yiur code in here

Comment: Without code it's hard to know, but maybe you need outline:none or :focus {outline:none;} (the first button might be in the focused state

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b2LxH/ added.  However it doesn't show under normal circumstances, just in the Chrome Extension (im using Chrome on OSX if it changes things)

Comment: Well it doesn't highlight for me: http://d.pr/i/mYIp

Comment: `outline: none;` should achieve what you want.

Comment: Just in the Chrome extension? Looks like it's just highlighting the first option for keyboard accessibility... try `tabindex="-1"` or just setting `outline: none;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `outline: none;` to your `.current` class works fine:

```
.current {
    border-bottom: 1px #0d6fac solid;
    outline: none;
}
```

Alternatively, try it on the `ul.nav`:

```
ul.nav a {
    outline: none;
}
```

See this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2LxH/1/).